# TailwindCSS: How do I center a child div that is wider than its parent and make it scrollable to both the left AND right?

Tags: tailwind-css

I am attempting to center a child div that is wider than its parent and allow it to be scrollable on either side horizontally. I can almost achieved this with overflow-x-scroll, and justify-center. The problem is that even though the div is centered, anything that overflows on the left is cut off by the browser completely. The content on the right is still scrollable. Is this possible to fix with Tailwind?

```
<div class="w-24 flex justify-center overflow-x-scroll">
  <div class="w-48">content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind is an abstraction of CSS. Currently, there is no way in CSS to set the default scroll position of an element, so we'd need to use JavaScript:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('div');
parent.scrollLeft = (parent.scrollWidth - parent.offsetWidth) * 0.5;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="w-24 flex overflow-x-scroll">
  <div class="w-48 shrink-0">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's what I thought/was afraid of. Thanks for the response!